# Objective-C Styling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So I have the following code, and I want to know which is considered better "style" in objective-c.

Option 1:

```
id temp = [dictionary objectForKey: @"aBooleanValue"];
BOOL var = (temp) ? [ temp intValue ] : NO;
```

Option 2:

```
BOOL var = ([dictionary objectForKey: @"aBooleanValue"]) ? [[dictionary objectForKey: @"aBooleanValue"] intValue ] : NO;
```

I believe the performance is relatively similar since hashmaps have constant lookup times. Is it worthwhile to have the temp variable if it's never used again?

Comment: Just an unrelated note: you really should be using `[whatever boolValue]` if possible, not `[whatever intValue]`.

Comment: What's wrong with: `BOOL var = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"aBooleanValue"] boolValue];` ??

Comment: addition to Jonathan Sterling: and if you want the integer value. You should use integerValue and use NSInteger instead of int and intValue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both options are valid, and neither is necessarily "better"; it's simply a matter of preference.

However, from what I can tell, there is a way you can shorten the code to the point where you don't need the variable or a ternary operator at all.
If the object returned from `[dictionary objectForKey:@"aBooleanValue"]` is an `NSNumber` or `NSValue` (which I'm assuming it is), you can avoid the issue completely by simply calling `BOOL var = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"aBooleanValue"] boolValue]` and be done with it.

Comment: aBooleanValue is newly added, so there should be backward compatibility for dictionaries (or files) that do not contain a value for this key. I don't believe I can call boolValue on nil...

Comment: @jp.rider63 You definitely can call `boolValue` on `nil`; calling methods on `nil` is a big deal in Objective-C (you should definitely check this topic out!). In this case, calling `boolValue` on `nil` will return `NO`.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought nil was defined as 0. I suppose this would be the best solution then (sorry V1ru8). I also read [link](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/02/messaging-nil-in-objective-c.html) for more background.

Comment: Great link! Yeah, working with `nil` is a fascinating topic (and the way the Objective-C runtime handles it is loads better than how `NULL` is handled in C).

Answer (score 3):

Itai Ferber's solution with boolValue sounds like a good solution. But never use Option 2. It's working correct but it gives you messy and ugly code that no one wants to read. Option 1 look more clear and can be read way better.
Most of the time the stuff you do to make code more clear. Like adding a tmp var is anyway optimized by the compiler so it doesn't make a difference.